# Getting the type of a value in std::map without knowing the key

Tags: c++, dictionary, reflection, stdmap, c++03

I have a map with unknown key and value types, and I want to determine the `typeid(...).name()` of the value type without knowing the key type beforehand:

```
 std::map<K, V> aMap;
 // This gives me the typeid(...).name(), but requires knowing the key type
 typeid(aMap[0]).name();
```

Is there any way to obtain the `typeid(...).name()` for `V` without knowing what type `K` is?

It should be noted that I am limited to C++03; however, if there is  way to do this in C++11 or beyond, it would be cool to know.

Comment: `decltype(aMap)::mapped_type` ?

Comment: @basil XY-Problem? Better describe what you want to achieve instead of **how** to get there?

Comment: @Justin I am looking for the type name of V as a string i.e. typeid(...).name(), but I  am unaware of what type K is.

Comment: @basil: Again: `typeid(decltype(aMap)::mapped_type).name()`

Comment: @Swordfish at the moment, I am limited to using C++03. I wish C++11 would be an option but alas....

Comment: "I am looking for the type name of V as a string"  - there is no way of doing that in standard C++ - i.e. you can't expect a std::string type to be able to produce "std::string" as a string.

Comment: @basil Thanks for reminding me that `decltype` is C++11

Comment: @NeilButterworth [`boost::core::demangle`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/core/doc/html/core/demangle.html#core.demangle.header_boost_core_demangle_hpp) works pretty well for demangling `typeid(...).name()`, at least for gcc and clang

Comment: @Justin Boost != Standard C++. And if your code depends on doing this, I would suggest it is very badly designed.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: seems to me like it depends on what sort of thing you're writing. Depending on it (or something similar) in a debugger seems entirely reasonable (but I'd certainly agree that's one of only a *few* good examples).

Comment: @Jerry The debugger should depend on debug information in the executable, not trying to decode c++ typeids. At least, that's my opinion. And anyway, it doesn't seem to be what the OP was asking about.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Fair enough--at least assuming it can depend on only ever dealing with executables that include debug info--but most will attempt to provide what they can, even when that's absent. I'd certainly prefer to use debug info when possible, but when (for whatever reason) it's not, decoding things like this can be a lot better than nothing (at least IMO).

Comment: @NeilButterworth I've used `boost::core::demangle` in unit tests involving a `std::type_info`. Basically, if the assertion failed, I could have a demangled name in the error message

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you at least know what you're dealing with is an `std::map`, you can use a template function to get to the key and value types more or less directly:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

template <class T, class U>
std::string value_type(std::map<T, U> const &m) {
    return typeid(U).name();
}

int main() { 
    std::map<int, std::string> m;

    std::cout << value_type(m);
}
```

The actual string that's printed out for `std::string` is implementation defined, but at least this gives you something that's intended to represent that type, without its being hard-coded into `value_type`, or anything like that.

In the specific case of `std::map`, you can use `mapped_type` instead--the template method above will also work for templates that don't define anything like that though.